Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1 : Operation not permitted
I working on a quarkus application. I was able to compile it locally and everything is working fine. But when trying to dockerize it it throws me this error :
copying /src/src/main/resources/application.yaml to /src/target/classes/application.yaml failed with FileSystemException: /src/target/classes/application.yaml: Operation not permitted
 

Here is the dockerfile i am currently using:
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk17:ubi

WORKDIR /src

USER 185
COPY . .

CMD ["./mvnw","compile","quarkus:dev"]


I tried to work with the default Dockerfile.jvm generated by quarkus and it is working fine. But the issue is i don't want to package the app every time before containerizing it. I would like to stick to the first dockerfile

Those two locations: /src/src/main/resources/application.yaml to /src/target/classes/application.yaml do not fit together... because the first one has /src/src while the second /src/... and also the usage of USER 185 looks weird...

Well i am new to Quarkus and Docker but when creating a new Quarkus project it generates dockerfiles ( which not the one above ) but it contains a USER 185

Please check the locations from my first comment... there does something not fit together ...
